# Always returning XML string with Json in a WCF Service

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf

I have the WCF Service that always is returning:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"> JSON STRING </string>
```

I just want the JSON STRING piece. I've read some posts here in stackoverflow and tried the solutions but I couldn't get anywhere. Here is my code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetUserById?x={uid}")]
    string getUserByUID(string uid);
```

Interface Implementation:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public string getUserByUID(string uid)
    {
        UserDAO mUserDAO = UserService.getUserDAO();
        User mUser = mUserDAO.getUserByUID(Convert.ToInt64(uid));
        if (mUser != null)
        {
            mUserDAO.close();
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mUser);
        }
```

Web Config:

```
    <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
```

The call made by Retrofit:

```
D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET http:http://localhost/UserService.svc/GetUserById?x=1
D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json
D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)
```

The return from the Server

```
D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://localhost/UserService.svc/GetUserById?x=1 (92ms)
D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 446
D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
D/Retrofit﹕ Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
D/Retrofit﹕ X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
D/Retrofit﹕ Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 03:32:53 GMT
D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1434598232505
D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1434598232588
D/Retrofit﹕ <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{JSON STRING}</string>
D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (446-byte body)
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you calling your service?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, I'm using Retrofit. I added the call and return data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the content type and accept type in order to receive JSON response.

I am not sure how are you calling your service. I will write an example in C#. However, it can be easily translated to any other language.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
wc.DownloadString("http://yourUrl.com/GetUserById?x=1");
```

It works for me :)

Comment: I changed the headers in the call but the service still send the <string...>. See the retrofit call information:D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET http://localhost/UserService.svc/GetUserById?x=1
D/Retrofit﹕ Accept: application/json
D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body). Thank you.

Comment: @Carlos I am having excate same probelm as you but im not consuming in a web client but I am using httpclient

Comment: @rogue39nin, I fixed it changing this line return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mUser); to return mUser;

Comment: yeah mine was messed up to trying to return a string insteasd of the object all working sweet now love the way

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the problem it was a infrastructure problem The FTP was not updating the site and the updates in the code were not reflected when I tested.

But I found that my code was also wrong. Below you can find the one that is working now. I hope it can help anyone else.

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public User getUserByUID(string uid)
    {
        UserDAO mUserDAO = UserService.getUserDAO();
        User mUser = mUserDAO.getUserByUID(Convert.ToInt64(uid));
        if (mUser != null)
        {
            mUserDAO.close();
            return mUser;
        }
```